# Python: Replace characters in string with equivalent in another string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to replace a character within a string with an equivalent character in another string.

String after changes made:

```
#C/084&"
#3*#%#C
```

Original String:

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
```

How can I replace **all** 'C's back to '+'?

Comment: Have you tried `str.replace`?

Comment: what makes characters "equivalent"?

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure what you mean by "equivalent character", but if you mean replace all occurrences of a  specific character anywhere in the string you can use `string.replace('C','+')`.

Comment: I should have explained my question better, but what I mean is that I want to be able to find where all the C are in the string and replace it with another character in another string that is in the same position as it, without having to actually mention '+' in my code.

Comment: ok, than that would be something like: `string.replace('C',another_string[some_index])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `original_str.replace('C', '+')`

Example:

```
>>> 'C++'.replace('C', '+')
'+++'
>>>
```

UPDATE:

```
first = list('C/084&"')
second = '3*#%#C'

for i, x in enumerate(first):
     first[i] = first[i] if x!='C' else second[i]

first = ''.join(first)
```

After it `first` is `3/084&"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also re module for eg.

```
import re

string1 = '#+/084&"'
string2 = re.sub("+", "C", string1)
>>>string2
'#C/084&"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with string.replace() function:

```
  string1 = "#3*#%#C"
  string2 = string1.replace("C","+")
  print(string2)
```